# Using jQuery to programmatically click an <a> link

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, click, anchor

I know this question has been asked before, but after a search on the web I can't seem to find a straight forward answer.

**the HTML**

```
<a id=myAnchor href=index.php>
```

**the jQuery** (Both of these do not work)

```
 $('#myAnchor').click();
```

or

```
$('#myAnchor').trigger('click');
```

What is the simplest and most efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: Click doesn't trigger the default behaviour of the link. This question has been asked many times before.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I call jquery click() to follow an <a> link if I haven't bound an event handler to it with bind or click already?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694595/can-i-call-jquery-click-to-follow-an-a-link-if-i-havent-bound-an-event-hand)

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053598/jquery-click-doesnt-work-on-hyperlink

Comment: I hope your HTML doesn't actually look like that. A normal HTML anchor looks like: `<a id="myAnchor" href="index.php">Text</a>` (with quotes and a proper closing tag).

Comment: @Cory: If you're not validating for XHTML, the quotes won't be required for those values.

Comment: @amnotiam: I know it's permitted to omit them, but the [HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2) does encourage them.

Answer (score 105):

Try this:

```
$('#myAnchor')[0].click();
```

It works for me.

Comment: This worked for me when literally nothing else has. Thank you a great deal! +1

Comment: This has problems with legacy browsers. Don't use it if you need broad compatibility.

Comment: I was looking for a Greasemonkey way, and this worked! Many thanks.

Comment: Thanks for this! I have been trying to figure out how to programatically click links for years. The gotcha for me was not having that "[0]" in there. What is that called, and why is it necessary?

Comment: Worked for me in IE Edge.

Comment: @EricHepperle-CodeSlayer2010, the `[0]` is a shorthand for `.get(0)` which returns the underlying DOM element to which the JQuery object is refers.  That allows you to call the `.click()` method directly on the DOM element, which works, rather than on the jQuery object, which does not work.

Comment: @10GritSandpaper Aha... thanks for explaining that! I get it now.

Answer (score 35):

```
window.location = document.getElementById('myAnchor').href
```

Comment: I prefer this method personally, as it avoids the need to create a 'faked' event.

Comment: This was once a popular way to redirect to a link, somehow it became a lost ancient technology nowadays :)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan only when the purpose of an anchor is to redirect you. What if it is not? What if it opens a modal? Or sends an ajax request? Or loads a page via pjax?

Comment: In those cases then you should just call the function that performs those actions directly, instead of faking a click event on a button.

Answer (score 25):

Click just triggers the click event / events not the actually "goto-the-links-href" action.

You have to write your own handler and then your **$('#myAnchor').trigger('click');** will work...

```
$("#myAnchor").click(function(event)
{
  var link = $(this);
  var target = link.attr("target");

  if($.trim(target).length > 0)
  {
    window.open(link.attr("href"), target);
  }
  else
  {
     window.location = link.attr("href");
  }

  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: My favorite as it addresses the issue of target. Does it trigger pop-up blockers though?

Answer (score 4):

```
<a href="#" id="myAnchor">Click me</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myAnchor').click(function(){
       window.location.href = 'index.php';
    });
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Add `onclick="window.location = this.href"` to your `<a>` element. After this modification it could be `.click()`ed with expected behaviour. To do so with every link on your page, you can add this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("a").attr("onclick", "window.location = this.href");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Just fyi: Doesn't work in IE7. DIE, IE7, DIE! Otherwise very nice workaround!

Answer (score 4):

I tried few of the above solutions but they didn't worked for me. Here is a link to the page which worked for me [automatically click a link](http://blog.stchur.com/2010/01/15/programmatically-clicking-a-link-in-javascript/)

Above link has many solutions and here's the one which worked for me,

```
    <button onclick="fun();">Magic button</button>

    <!--The link you want to automatically click-->
    <a href='http://www.ercafe.com' id="myAnchor">My website</a>
```

Now within the `<script>` tags,

```
<script>

     function fun(){
          actuateLink(document.getElementById('myAnchor'));
     }

     function actuateLink(link)
     {
          var allowDefaultAction = true;

          if (link.click)
          {
              link.click();
              return;
          }
          else if (document.createEvent)
          {
              var e = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
              e.initEvent(
                   'click'     // event type
                   ,true      // can bubble?
                   ,true      // cancelable?
              );
              allowDefaultAction = link.dispatchEvent(e);           
          }

          if (allowDefaultAction)       
          {
              var f = document.createElement('form');
              f.action = link.href;
              document.body.appendChild(f);
              f.submit();
          }
    }

</script>
```

Copy paste the above code and click on clicking the `'Magic button'` button, you will be redirected to `ErCafe.com`.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for my situation! Some people even say the jQuery click simply works--not at all for me. This solution is awesome.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue. try this `$('#myAnchor').get(0).click();`this works for me

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, you can do it with `jQuery.trigger` http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <a id="foo" onclick="action()"></a>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function action(){
            window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com/q/9081426/5526354")
        }

        $("#foo").trigger("click");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for compatibility;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                window.location.href = $('#myAnchor').attr("href");

            }, 1500);
        });
    </script>
```