# How to open new html file using java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Suppose I have two html files:  'page1' and 'page2'

**Code in page1:**

```
<html>

<body>
page1
<a href="page2.html" target="_blank"> click to go to page 2</a>
</body>

</html>
```

**Code in page2:**

```
<html>

<body>
page2
<a href="page1.html" target="_blank"> click to go to page 1 </a>
</body>

</html>
```

Using this I can open page2 using hyperlink in page1 in a new tab in the same window and viceversa

Is it possible to the same thing using javascript

Comment: use `window.open(urlhere)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make a redirect page in jQuery/JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript)

Comment: use `location.href = "page2.html";` if you want to open a page in the same window.

Comment: I am using a button, I am using 'window.open('page2.html','_newtab');' in it, and I am supposed to open more than 2 new tabs in just one click, but I am unable to do that since only the last tab is opening, its like the last tab is kinda overwriting the previous ones

Comment: The OP is asking for a new tab, not the current page nor popup.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opening new window/tab without using \`window.open\` or \`window.location.href\`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11735889/opening-new-window-tab-without-using-window-open-or-window-location-href)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lots of way possible ..

1.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    window.location.href="login.jsp?backurl="+window.location.href;
</script>
```

2.

```
<script language="javascript">
    alert("back");
    window.history.back(-1);
</script>
```

3.

```
<script language="javascript">
    window.navigate("top.jsp");
</script>
```

4.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    self.location="top.htm";
</script>
```

5.

```
<script language="javascript">
    alert("Access Violation");
    top.location="error.jsp";
</script>
```

6.

```
<script language="javascript">
    window.location = window.location.host;
</script>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for giving so many options it helped me a lot...

Answer (score 0):

check this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript).you can use

```
// similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");

// similar behavior as clicking on a link
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `click` event listener to your link element (or any other) and set the `href` property in the `location` object. Let’s use inline `onclick` for illustration:

```
<a href="index.html" onclick="location.href='index.html';return false;">Link</a>
```

By clicking on this element, the `onclick` handler will be executed, setting the `href`, i.e. the current address. By returning `false`, the default action will be prevented (see [MouseClick.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault)).

This is kind of a JavaScript surrogate for HTML hypertext behavior. You also can do other cool things with [Window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location).