# Jquery not working when revisiting a page

Tags: jquery, jira

I have this snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
AJS.$(document).ready(function() {
    AJS.$('#show-more-links-link').click();
})
</script>
```

It clicks a link. It works OK when the page with the link is loaded/reloaded, but when it is revisited, it doesn't. (`AJS.$` is method for using Jquery in Jira).

Any ideas?

Comment: When you go back to the page, does the page actually reload? Or does it just restore from the browser's cache (and therefore not call document ready)?

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to have a handler for your click:

Try:

```
 AJS.$('#show-more-links-link').click(function() {

 alert("Whatever you wanted to do here");

 });
```

Comment: Thanks, what I need is that Jquery click that link for me.

Comment: I think this question could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081426/using-jquery-to-programmatically-click-an-a-link

Comment: Thanks, I solved the problem, it had to do with the way Jira handle page events.