# Click an anchor tag inside another click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

Is there a way to click an anchor tag inside another event. What I have here does not seem to work:

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/my7oxtL0/1/

JS:

```
$('.mybutton').click(function(){
    //other stuff runs
    $("#link1").click();
});
```

html:

```
<button class="mybutton">click me</button>
<a id="link1" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank"></a>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23904765/4028085

Comment: Here is working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9h1twu2q/1/

Comment: Another option woud be `window.location = $("#link1").attr('href');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
$('.mybutton').click(function(){
    //other stuff runs
    document.getElementById("link1").click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me know why you are trying anchor tag click in here ? You can try with window.open() method to do

```
Window.open($("#anchor").attr('href'));
```