# how to auto click in javascript or html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can somebody tell me how to auto click the button in a page when it loads?
I've tried this code in javascript but it doesn't `work.

```
<a href="javascript:Clickheretoprint()" id="print">

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#print").click(); 
});
</script>
```

is there any way to do this??

Comment: That should work. Are there any errors in the console? Have you included JQuery?

Comment: use `$("#print").trigger("click")`

Comment: `document.body.load=function()` try .

Comment: Do check if the page has more than one element with same id `#print`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using jQuery to programmatically click an <a> link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081426/using-jquery-to-programmatically-click-an-a-link)

Comment: are you referencing a jQuery script in your code? No jQuery tag is on the question, but you are using it

Answer (score 0):

Please try following :

```
$("#print")[0].click();
```

The answer is from the following link :

[Using jQuery to programmatically click an <a> link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081426/using-jquery-to-programmatically-click-an-a-link)

Comment: As this answer ( http://stackoverflow.com/a/23904765/1675954) will doubtfully be deleted (as it has 61 votes), you would have been better to submit this as a duplicate question

Comment: @RachelGallen I agree with you. I will delete my answer and try to mark it as duplicate.