# Internet Explorer 8 JQuery Click() function not working

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I am really struggling with IE8 not recognizing my JQuery Click() function.  Chrome and FF works fine. I have searched through several pages of google search for the right answer but have yet to identify a solution.  I came across several stackoverflow posts, but no result. Usually the situations are way more complicated than what I am doing.

```
<a id="modalwindow" class="thickbox" href="iframemodal.html?placeValuesBeforeTB_=savedValues&TB_iframe=true&height=300&width=425&modal=true"></a>

<script language="javascript">
//<!--
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#modalwindow').click();
});
//-->
</script>
```

Pretty simple yes? I am trying to force a "click" on the link that is using a thickbox plugin to pop up a modal-style window.  I also tried using

```
$('#modalwindow').trigger('click');
```

But that will not work either.  I am getting no javascript errors, and I can do alerts before and after the click() and they function fine.  I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

The click event call will not enforce an actual click, but it will call any click handler code that you may have.  If you want to have the link "clicked", then do this:

```
location.href = $('#modelwindow').attr('href');
```

Comment: Looks like he's using some server-side technology that I don't recognize. This code will fail for a different reason, though. See my answer.

Comment: You are correct when you are saying that the click() function will not actually click the link, but if he has a click event handler somewhere else in the code, then that event handler will be called.

Comment: Hmm, well I was assuming he wanted to follow the href link. If he's triggering another handler then it's a different story.

Comment: The slashes were from a PHP echo statement. They are irrelevant to this issue and I have now edited them out. I also previously edited out the $ifl PHP variable which is not relevant to this.  Yes I have tested with it removed as well.

Answer (score 0):

See this: [jquery click doesn't work on hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053598/jquery-click-doesnt-work-on-hyperlink)

JQuery's click() doesn't *actually* click on the link, it just executes all attached event handlers.

Comment: That should be irrelevant since he's using thickbox to display it. (At least I'm assuming thickbox is like fancybox and lightbox)

Comment: Correct, thickbox is similar to those. It is a jquery plugin to open lightbox style windows etc.  http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/

Comment: I see. Funny, just two days ago I was writing my own version of this exact thing, but I see that it can open URL's as iframes in the overlay by using `<a href/>`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I'm also have  this problem . This cause my button interaction are delayed 
with the real result we want .

My situation is that I have two button A and B

If I click A than B should be click ( or show it is click by some mean to represent it )

```
$("A").click(function(){
   $("B").trigger("click");
})
```

but when I testing it on firefox and chrome are not delayed .

and when I testing it on ie8 ( embeded in ietester ) 
I should click A button two times and the B button would show click status .

my first way to resolve this problem is that 
change the trigger to click

```
$("A").click(function(){
   $("B").click();
})
```

but still delayed on ie 8

and I do this twise

```
$("A").click(function(){
  $("B").click();
  $("B").click();
 })
```

then it works fine .

I don't know wether you could solve by the final method I did .

When I test it , it works fine ~