# asp:HyperLink trigger click with JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, hyperlink, click

I'm dynamically populating a table with a repeater and I want to trigger an asp:HyperLink when there is a click on a row.

```
<td id="hyperLink">
       <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkDocPage_<%# Eval("ID")%>" ClientIDMode="Static" NavigateUrl="~/Pages/DocumentListPage.aspx?id=<%# Eval("ID")%>" Text="" runat="server">link</asp:HyperLink>
</td>
```

This is the td with the hyperlink.

And here is the script, that unfortunately does not redirect the user to the DocumentListPage page.

```
function bindRowClick() {
    $('#productTable').find('tr').click(function () {
        var id = $(this).find('th:first').text().replace(/\s+/g, " ");
        id = ($.trim(id)).split(' ')[1];
        var lnkButtonID = '#lnkDocPage_' + id;
        alert($(lnkButtonID).attr('href'));
        window.location = $(lnkButtonID).attr('href');
    });
}
```

Since each hyperlink has a unique ID depending on the row I firstly calculate the id.
I've tried to see if the selector '$(lnkButtonID)' is working - yes it seems that I'm obtaining the hyperlink, but for some reason I can not redirect to the NavigateUrl of the hyperlink.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: in your code you get the **href** attr but still didnt fire the click event

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery click doesn't work on hyperlink](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053598/jquery-click-doesnt-work-on-hyperlink)

Comment: I've added 'alert($(lnkButtonID).attr('href'));' and the resilt is 'undefined'

Comment: @AntonBelev that is because the ID on ASP hyperlinks when rendered on the front end gets prefixed with control names/IDs e.g. `control1_lnkDocPage_`. Thus, when you're doing `$('#lnkDocPage')` you're not actually getting the required element.

Comment: @kayen `<asp:hyperlink id="lnkDocPage_50" cssclass="hyperLink" clientidmode="Static" navigateurl="~/Pages/DocumentListPage.aspx?id=50" text="--&gt;" runat="server">link</asp:hyperlink>`  I've copied this from the page's HTML the id is `lnkDocPage_50`

Comment: Can you do a view source on the page and check the ID of the anchor tag again?

Comment: Last line, try to set the window.location.href instead of the window.location

Comment: it seems that the problem is that the href is undefined ... I don't know why, even if I change it to 'window.location.href ' won't make any difference at this point

Comment: looking at your answer to @kayen , you really have asp.net markup in your rendered html page ? If so, that's the issue. Does alert($(lnkButtonID).attr('navigateurl')) return a value ?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do it using:

```
$('table').on('click', 'tr', function () {
    $(this).find('a[id*="lnkDocPage_"]').trigger('click');
});
```

The expression `id*="lnkDocPage_"` matches elements which have an `id` containing  `lnkDocPage_` and triggers a click event on it when the table row it is nested in is clicked.

If you just have a single anchor tag within every `tr` element:

```
$('table').on('click', 'tr', function () {
    $(this).find('a').trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use event beforeunload, because of navigating to a different page all functionality is disabled.

window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();//or show progress bar...

});

Answer (score 0):

```
<td id="hyperLink">
       <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkDocPage_<%# Eval("ID")%>" ClientIDMode="Static" NavigateUrl="~/Pages/DocumentListPage.aspx?id=<%# Eval("ID")%>" Text="" runat="server">link</asp:HyperLink>
</td>
```

Below is the Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#productTable').find('tr').click(function () {
           $(this).find('a[id^="lnkDocPage_"]').trigger("click");
        });
});
```