# Jquery settimeout button click inside its own handler

Tags: jquery, return, settimeout

Here's a wierd one for you all - I believe the issue is related to either returning false or the initial void. I have a button ....

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="csv1" onclick="formexport(vars etc)">Click me<a>
```

Then inside the function I make an ajax call to a php page that generates an Excel file based on the variables passed to it, and then on completion removes the onclick property and replaces the href property with a link to the newly created file and then clicks the button again. e.g....

```
function formexport(what, formname, tabid, start, finish, folder){
    $filename = ("/clients/" + folder + "/" + $formname + "-" + finish + ".csv");
    $.ajax({
        url: "formexport.php?rand=" + new Date().valueOf(),
        type: "POST",
        data: { start: start, finish: finish, tab: tabid, form: formname, filename: $filename }
    }).done(function(data){
            $('#' + what).attr('href', data).removeAttr('onclick');
            setTimeout(function() { $('#' + what).click(); }, 20);
    });
    return false;
}
```

"What" is simply the id of the button so that it can be targeted again. This all works except the 2nd button click. If I hover over the button the href has indeed changed to the file link but it is never auto-clicked the 2nd time.
Is it the return false from the initial function, or the javascript:void(0), I am not sure? Any help greatly appreciated. I read elsewhere on Stack where people were loading files into frames and all sorts of things to get file links to work, but this strikes me as more logical and cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Another StackOverflow question, [jquery click doesn't work on hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053598/jquery-click-doesnt-work-on-hyperlink), gives a simple answer to "why doesn't this work":

> The important thing to note is that it does not duplicate clicking the link. It only triggers associated events.

There is potentially a very simple solution to your query, unless there's something significant your question doesn't mention. Just change:

```
  $('#' + what).attr('href', data).removeAttr('onclick');
  setTimeout(function() { $('#' + what).click(); }, 20);
```

to:

```
  window.location.href = data;
```

Comment: Gidday Adrian, thanks for the reply bud :-) That was what I initially had in there and it doesn't work either (neither does document.location.href). It's almost as though removing the onclick attribute removes further processing of the current function. Iam stumped - everything works except anything after that removeAttr line. A possible solution might be to call the setTimeout from outside the function?

Comment: What is the value of data, then - is it possible that there's something else in the string that's not been noticed? How about `window.open()` instead?

Comment: Also tried that earlier too bud :-) The value of data is the path to the file e.g. http://www.yyyyy.com/clients/clientfolder/mytab10.20.2013.csv
What I might do is just get the ajax request to return success and get the php file to issue headers for the link