# .click() not getting fired over an anchor tag after modifying its download attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My case is that "System needs to ask to the user that 'are you going to open the image or to download it.?' by using a confirm box.. If user presses okay we should not prevent the default action of that anchor tag, let it go, but if user presses cancel the particular image should get downloaded...

HTML:

```
<a href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=3c6263c3453b">test</a>
```

JS:

```
$('a').click(function (e) {
    if (!$(this).is('[download]')) {
        var cond = confirm('Press ok to view, cancel to save..');
        if (!cond) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).attr('download', 'download').click().removeAttr('download');
        }
    }
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/94Hra/1/)

Can anybody tell how to achieve this..?

Comment: Will the .trigger() event be of some use?http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: @NishanthiGrashia I think both are same.. I tried it after seeing your comment.. but it was not responding..

Comment: [This](https://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/18969/jquery-click-events-not-firing-based-on-class-attribute-getting-desperate-please-help) might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `this.click();` as [HTMLElement.click()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.click) method simulates a mouse click on an element.

Whereas `$(this).click();`  will only trigger jquery click handler and `onclick` handler bounded to element nothing else.

```
$('a').click(function (e) {
    if (!$(this).is('[download]')) {
        var cond = confirm('Press ok to view, cancel to save..');
        if (!cond) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).attr('download', 'download');
            this.click()
            $(this).removeAttr('download');
        }
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/88dn8/)

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy your event is called, but it doesn't do anything because your link `.is('[download]')`, programatically triggering the click using jQuery does not simulate a link click (which is what you need). [See this question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053598/jquery-click-doesnt-work-on-hyperlink)

Comment: @billyonecan Your comment was very useful, it clarified my doubt fully and you guys just taught a new concept to me which i did not know before...

Answer (score 1):

Try with this, `$("a")[0].click()` will do the trick

```
$('a').click(function (e) {
    if (!$(this).is('[download]')) {
        var cond = confirm('Press ok to view, cancel to save..');
        if (!cond) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).attr('download', 'download');
            $("a")[0].click().removeAttr('download');
        }
    }
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/94Hra/19/)

Comment: And also it is not removing the attribute, since it is not a Jquery object.. And i wonder why did jquery's `click()` not work.? Can anybody tell me the exact reason..?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy, You can use `this.click();$(this).removeAttr('download');` instead of `$("a")[0].click().removeAttr('download');` http://jsfiddle.net/88dn8/ You very well know how to do it

Comment: @Satpal but why `this.click();` instead of `$(this).click();`.

Comment: @Satpal Yeah.. by using `this.click();` i temporarily fixed it in my proj.. But why didn't `$(this).click()` work..? This is really mysterious..

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy, `$(this).click();` jquery click will only trigger jquery click handler and `onclick` handler bounded to element nothing else.

Comment: @Satpal but as i know `this.click();` here **this** is a dom node, and here `$(this).click();` **$(this)** is a jQuery object, so the question is why `click()` method of jQuery working with dom node but not with jquery object. ^^

Comment: @Jai, `this.click()` is a [HTMLElement.click()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.click) which simulates mouse click thus works.

Comment: @Jai A useful comment.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24571041/click-not-getting-fired-over-an-anchor-tag-after-modifying-its-download-attri#comment38062477_24571769

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').click(function (e) {
  if (!$(this).is('[download]')) {
  var resp = confirm("Press ok to view, cancel to save..!");
   if (resp == true) {
  // You pressed OK
    e.preventDefault();
    } else {
  //    Pressed Cancel!";
     $(this).attr('download', 'download').click().removeAttr('download');
   }        
  }
});
```

here you go working fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/sajrashid/94Hra/18/

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to mess with event bubbling with this one. Let the browser's default behavior take care of everything. Calling events manually always creates a mess. Control behavior with the `download` attribute. Add it or remove it based on your condition and pass the ball to browser.

## [Demo](http://jsbin.com/fitifugu/4/edit)

### Code:

```
$('a').click(function (e) {
    var cond = confirm('Press ok to view, cancel to save..');
    if (!cond) {
        $(this).attr('download', 'download');
    } else {
        $(this).removeAttr('download');
    }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

I checked your code and got a solution
So you have to change your code a bit

you have add a name tag in your anchor tag like

```
<a href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=3c6263c3453b" name="myevent">test</a>
```

Now replace your code

```
$('a').click(function (e) {
```

With this one

```
$(document).on("click","a[name='myevent']", function (e) {
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/94Hra/15/ Not working..? And i don't think that this the problem.. :\